# Does boto3 or aws cli have Create Template from Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I noticed the aws console has "Create Template from Instance" option.[image] Is there a boto3 or aws cli equivalent?

I want to create a launch template using python + boto3 from a given instance-id. However I don't want to go through all the minute details used to create the instance.

I've found the documentation for [create_launch_template](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_launch_template) but did not see anything similar to this option.

Comment: I suspect that this is a feature of the Amazon EC2 management console rather than a specific API call (just like "Launch More Like This"). You can verify this by using the command then looking at CloudTrail to see what API calls were performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find any cli or boto3 api equivalent to "create template from instance" console option.